# 'I went here to venerate the priest martyr.'- is this sentence's translation to French natural?

Tags: expressions, traduction

I'd like to know the translation to French of the expression 'I went here to venerate the martyred priest.', since I have no knowledge in French.

the Google translator tells me this sentence - 'Je suis allé ici eto vénérer le martyr français et le prêtre.'

but I doubt if this sentence is correct. Is there a more accurate and polite way of saying this sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your translation's no good, it gives the impression there might be more than one person involved.  *The priest martyr* in French is l*e prêtre et martyr*, where both *prêtre* and *martyr* are nouns.  If you said *le prêtre martyr*, *martyr* would be an adjective and it would be *the martyred priest* in English.  I don't know where you get *français* from the English and *eto* doesn't mean anything at all in French.  One last thing, *je suis allé ici* sounds a bit odd, you should say *je suis venu*.

To sum up, a way to translate the English could be :

> - Je suis venu vénérer le prêtre et martyr.

Comment: Yes. The martyred priest sounds right. I got that sentence from google translator..

Comment: *Vénérer le prêtre et **le** martyr* is probably what I would have used. I guess the context should make clear that it is the same person.

Comment: @jiliagre    Je crois qu'il est d'usage de se référer ainsi ("prêtre et martyr") aux prêtres inscrits au martyrologe de l'Eglise.